# DOMcollection.js failed to compile in React Environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: The Structure of the Project is shown in the photo]I am new to react and there is a problem while solving the error.

May I ask please what is missing in my project environment please?

The following message appears:

```
**Failed to compile**

./node_modules/@testing-library/dom/node_modules/pretty-format/build/plugins/DOMCollection.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (53:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                 return props;
|               }, {})
|             : {...collection},
|           config,
|           indentation,
```

[image: the snapshot of the project structure]

**webpack.config.dev.js** file:

This file is being generated after the `npm run eject` command.

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');
```

Comment: can you provide the code from your webpack.config,js file?

Comment: @Ran marciano, thank you for your reply. May I ask please where to find the webpack.config.js file?

Comment: how did you create the project? using create-react-app?

Comment: yes, I created the project using create-react-app. Then uploded my public and src folders on GitHub. Now cloned it on my laptop and installed npm package again and then run ti with npm start command.

Comment: To get webpack.config.js file you can run "npm run eject".
It should be inside the config folder.
Now before you cloned it, did it worked?

Comment: It says, Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, and try again.

Comment: Makes sense, its just asking you to commit the last changes you've mad

Comment: @RanMarciano, unfortunately, problem still persists. May i ask please what is the issue? Are you also facing the same issue?

Comment: The code you've provided is the whole webpack.config file?
Basically, there are some problems that I know that can cause this issue and they are originated in the webpack.config.js file

Comment: I reinstalled ```npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react``` and it gives some warning about dependencies.

Comment: No, I just put few lines from ```webpack.config.dev.js```file.

Comment: I'm also getting this same error... was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a good long term solution but I was having this issue and changed react-scripts to version 4.0.1 with npm install react-scripts@4.0.1 and my dev environment is up again.

Comment: Could you explain why you did this?

Comment: [New React app failed to compile immediatly following install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66127456/16203449) In this post a user mentions  very vaguely a problem with react scripts and changing the version as a solution to a very similar issue, so I thought it would be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the first step is having the DOMCollection.js file opened and then resolving the {...collection} to collection,
Save the file and reload the page.[DOMCollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b90Wi.png)

so from  : {...collection}
config,
indentation,
depth,
refs,
printer

to :
collection,
config,
indentation,
depth,
refs,
printer