# New React app failed to compile immediatly following install

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have been using React Native for a while but figured I would try out React on the web. So I followed this guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html but after using `npx create-react-app react-try` , navigating to the new folder, and typing `yarn start` I get this error message:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js 1:60
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:60)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/e096752/Documents/Cole's Git Repos/react-try/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
```

This is everything that was included with the create method:
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WyvT.png)

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-try",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If there is any other info you need please let me know. What in the world do I need to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with
react-scripts 4.0.2.
A workaround is to change version manually to 4.0.1 on package.json then run `yarn install`.
That will do!

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did. I meant to delete this question but forgot to. Thanks for the answer though now other people can see it.

Comment: Same problem with "react-scripts": "4.0.3".
With "react-scripts": "4.0.1", it works !

Answer (score 3):

this problem happened for me because of the single quotation in the folder name, removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just followed the terminal log and the issue was resolved:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-loader" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

Answer (score 1):

I used this below npm command. I get out of this problem. let's try once this 
`npm link`

Answer (score 1):

package.json -> change version to 4.0.1 in "react-scripts": "4.0.1" ->run npm install again

Answer (score 1):

First update your `react-scripts` and remove webpack from your packages.json if you added.

Then you need to clear webpack cache so for doing this the ease way is remove `node_modules` and install them again

Answer (score 0):

If your folder name has  quotation marks like sample'app / "sample app",
remove those quotation marks or delete folder and create app react app from first.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, changing the "react-scripts": "4.0.2" -> "react-scripts": "4.0.1" in package.json file works.
same goes for  "react-scripts": "4.0.3" -> "react-scripts": "4.0.1"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not helpful to repeat another answer (in this case, @fabiangamboa95's). Try answering an unanswered question instead. :-)

Answer (score -3):

This mostly happens with loaders when one or more of the directories in your source file URL has an apostrophe.

in my own case it was;

> $ react-scripts start Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/index.js 1:43 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:43) File
> was processed with these loaders:
> ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js *
> ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.jsYou
> may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.>
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/PETER'S/PROJECTS/REACT
> APPS/EGAS/egas/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');|
> $RefreshSetup$(module.id);

you can quickly fix this by opening this file;

"*Project root directory*\node_modules@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\loader\RefreshModule.runtime.js"

then change this line;

```
$RefreshRuntime$ = require('$RefreshRuntimePath$');
```

to the absolute URL equivalent (in my case);

```
$RefreshRuntime$ = require("C:/Users/PETER'S/PROJECTS/REACT APPS/project-root/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js");
```

Comment: I don't think you should be editing anything in your `node_modules`. You'll lose it on the next install.