# Create React App produces app that won't compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I used the code:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

dozens of times last year to initiate new React.js applications. Today, when I tried doing the same thing, the resulting application won't compile...a dump from my console (I only shortened the project folder path to "my-path" for brevity.):

```
$ npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.0.0.215/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\my-path\my-app\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

./src/index.js 1:97
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:97)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/my-path/my-app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
```

Crazy, right? Does anyone know how I can fix this? Will it require "npm run eject" and some monkeying around with webpack (uugggh!)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New React app failed to compile immediatly following install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127456/new-react-app-failed-to-compile-immediatly-following-install)

Comment: I will try it, but I was wondering if there was a fix for the current version of react-scripts. I guess there isn't. Thanks!