# Webpack says 'you may need an additional loader' in React.js project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I created a React project with two workspaces, 'webmail' and 'component'. I put a small tsx file in 'component', I want to use that in 'webmail'. This is the package.json of component:

```
{
  "name": "@monorepo/component",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Creating a component module project",
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "component",
    "npm"
  ],
  "author": "Christine",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is webpack.config.js in component

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: { import: "./src/index.tsx" }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    mode: "production",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

This is 'MyComponent':

```
import React from "react-dom";

interface ComponentProps {
   label: string
}

export const MyComponent=({label, ...props}: ComponentProps)=> {

    return (
        <div>
            <button>{label}</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the tsx file that uses MyComponent:

```
import './css/App.css';
import React from 'react'
import { MyComponent } from "@monorepo/component"
function App() {

   return (
        <div className="flex flex-col h-screen w-screen">
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className='flex-wrap flex justify-between w-4/6'>
                    <div className='flex-wrap flex '>
              <MyComponent label='my button'/>

                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

What happens is that the webmail app launches, then complains about

```
ERROR in ../component/src/index.tsx 4:0
Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (4:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| import React from "react-dom";
> interface ComponentProps {
|    label: string
| }
```

Edit:
If I remove the 'interface' in the component code, the error I get is

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:8)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
|     return (
>         <div>
|             <button>{label}</button>
|         </div>
ERROR in ../component/src/index.tsx 9:8
```

If I change the 'index.tsx' in the component to 'index.js', I get

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

Somehow, the react preset for babel isn't picked up, I think. I have tried putting the preset line in package.json or in webpack.config.json or in babelrc.json. Is there anything wrong in my configs?

### Solution

I used [this](https://dev.to/ynwd/how-to-create-react-monorepo-with-npm-workspace-webpack-and-create-react-app-2dhn) as an example for my project. I now recreated that example locally, it gave me the same error that I had for a tsx component. After putting this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

in tsconfig.js, and adding the preset-typescript line suggested in two answers, the problem was solved, or so it seems for now.

Comment: I recently upgraded my project to webpack 5, and I found that (contrary to webpack 4) the default ts-loader supplied with webpack is easier to use and properly configure than trying to use babel for typescript (but kept babel for transpiling down to es5 javascript). Note that `interface` is a type-script language feature, not a React feature.

Comment: I got a similar error without the interface, about html elements in the source file. I use webpack 5.

Comment: Leave all of your implementations, Kick off with NextJs.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, does it, Amerlica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two clear issues, both related to your **component** workspace.

1. Add `@babel/preset-typescript` to your webpack configuration to remove the TypeScript syntax.

   ```
   npm i @babel/preset-typescript --save-dev
   ```

   ```js
   use: {
     loader: "babel-loader",
     options: {
       presets: [
         '@babel/preset-env',
         '@babel/preset-react',
         '@babel/preset-typescript' // <--- add this
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update the `main` field in the package.json to point  to the webpack build's `output` location.

   ```json
   "main": "dist/index.js"
   ```

Now make sure you build the **component** workspace before running the **webmail** workspace.

You may want/need to place the preset configurations inside of a **babel.config.json** file:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

There may be other issues with how you are trying to build and run your **webmail** workspace, but it is hard to say without more information on how it is configured and how you are running that workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I had a kind of same issue I fixed like this.

```
npm install ts-loader typescript --save-dev
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./src/index.tsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    mode: "production",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

For .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: I alread tried that, it gives me the same error....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127456/new-react-app-failed-to-compile-immediatly-following-install

Maybe this help.